# How can I validate that req.body has a valid date string using Joi in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have made a validation middleware whose code is given below like this.

```
export const validateMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {

    const validateExpression = Joi.object()
        .keys({
            'startDate': Joi.string()
                .optional()
                .allow(''),
             'endDate': Joi.string()
                 .optional()
                 .allow('')
        });

    const {
        error
    } = validateExpression.validate(req.query, {
        'convert': false,
        'abortEarly': false
    });

    if (error) {
       // Return response regarding that error.
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

I need to validate that `startDate` and `endDate` fields should be string of format `YYYY-MM-DD` also need to validate that `startDate` < `endDate` date value. How can I achieve this using Joi in Node JS ?.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will solve your problem:

```
const validateExpression = Joi.object()
  .keys({
    'startDate': Joi.date()
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
      .optional()
      .allow(''),
    'endDate': Joi.date()
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
      .optional()
      .allow('')
      .min(Joi.ref('startDate'))
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```javascript
const Joi = require("joi").extend(require("@joi/date"));


export const validateMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {

    const validateExpression = Joi.object()
        .keys({
            'startDate': Joi.date()
                .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                .strict(false) // required if 'convert' option is set to "false"
                .optional()
                .allow(''),
             'endDate': Joi.date()
                .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                .greater(Joi.ref("startDate")) // checks if it is greater than startDate, throws error if now.
                .strict(false) // can be omitted if 'convert' option is set to "true"
                .optional()
                .allow('')
        });

    const {
        error
    } = validateExpression.validate(req.query, {
        'convert': false,
        'abortEarly': false
    });

    if (error) {
       // Return response regarding that error.
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

**DO NOT** forget to call `strict(false)`. Otherwise passing **date** as string won't work, since you have `'convert': false`. Or alternatively, you can set `'convert': true` (which is the default value anyway) and you won't need to call `string(false)` on **startDate** and **endDate**.